# VB6 Log10 function

Tags: vb6, ieee-754

First question for me, please be gentle.

I have a Log10 function which I'm very happy with

```
Public Function Log10(ByVal n As Long) As Long

    Select Case n
        Case Is >= 1000000000: Log10 = 9
        Case Is >= 100000000: Log10 = 8
        Case Is >= 10000000: Log10 = 7
        Case Is >= 1000000: Log10 = 6
        Case Is >= 100000: Log10 = 5
        Case Is >= 10000: Log10 = 4
        Case Is >= 1000: Log10 = 3
        Case Is >= 100: Log10 = 2
        Case Is >= 10: Log10 = 1
        Case Else: Log10 = 0
    End Select

End Function
```

However, when creating a test for this function (I know it's trivial, and I know it works - QA etc) which looks like this

```
Public Const LONG_MAX As Long = 2147483647

Public Sub testLog10()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long

    For i = 1 To LONG_MAX
        DoEvents
        a = Log10(i)
        b = Int(Log(i) / Log(10))
        Debug.Assert a = b
    Next

End Sub
```

A often does not equal B, which, as you can imagine was quite a surprise, since the primary logarithm identity should always hold. If you abstract it into a function,

```
Private Function Log10(ByVal n As Long) As Long
    Dim d As Double
    d = Log(n) / Log(10)
    DblLog10 = Int(d)
End Function
```

Then you'll see that when n=10, d=1, which is correct. However, when it is converted into an int, it truncates it to zero. For those interested, Fix doesn't make a difference (it shouldn't anyway)) This is fixable by,

```
Private Function Log10(ByVal n As Long) As Long
    Dim d As Double
    d = Log(n) / Log(10) + 0.000000001
    DblLog10 = Int(d)
End Function
```

which implies the internal representation of double, whilst showing in the VB6 IDE as exactly one, is nothing of the sort.

Anyway, the question is: am I missing something, or is it simply something I must do. It's not of vital importance since this is a test function, not production code. More than anything, I'm just interested.

Answer (score 0):

A VB6 Double is a binary floating-point number type. You will get rounding errors when you do arithmetic. Don't worry!

You sound like a mathematical person so you should probably find out more about this. It'll be useful if you're programming numerical stuff. Try reading this. It's a c# article but the same principles hold in VB6.

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent `Double` idiosyncrasies by converting result temporary to `String` like this

```
Private Function Log10(ByVal n As Long) As Long
    Dim d As Double
    d = Log(n) / Log(10)
    Log10 = Int(CStr(d))
End Function
```

This has a slight hit on performance though if you are going to call the function in a tight loop.